# Packing DLLs in Java, difference between "System.load" and "System.loadLibrary"

Tags: java

I'm using a third party Java library (choco-solver) that depends on another library wrote in C++ (ibex). Also, I have a small project that uses these dependencies, so I need to pack a Jar (myapp.jar) with all these dependencies (choco-solver and ibex). My project will be used by another projects. For now, I've bundled all this dependencies in the jar file as in the following example:

```
mylib
--+ src
  |--+ main
     |--+ java
     |  |--+ // my code that uses choco-solver+ibex
     |--+ resources
        |--+ platform
           |--+ linux
           |  |--+ // *.so
           |--+ windows
              |--+ // *.dlls
```

And the following code to load these libraries:

```java
public static void loadLibraries() {
    String libPath = createLibFolder();
    if (libPath != null) {
        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
            loadWindowsDll(libPath, "platform/windows/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll");
            loadWindowsDll(libPath, "platform/windows/libstdc++-6.dll");
            loadWindowsDll(libPath, "platform/windows/ibex.dll");
            loadWindowsDll(libPath, "platform/windows/ibex-java.dll");
        } else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
            loadLinuxSO(libPath, "platform/linux/libibex.so");
            loadLinuxSO(libPath, "platform/linux/libibex-java.so");
        }
    }
    loaded = true;
}

private static void loadWindowsDll(String dllPath, String dllFileName) {
    try {
        InputStream in = IbexUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(dllFileName);
        String dllName = dllFileName.substring(
                dllFileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                dllFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        File temp = Paths.get(dllPath, dllName + ".dll").toFile();
        copyFile(in, temp);
        System.load(temp.toString());
        System.loadLibrary(dllName); // <- Here is the problem
    } catch (Exception re) {
        re.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

In the source code I highlighted the line that's causing the problem to me. The external Java library (choco-solver), who uses the C++ library (ibex), load those dependencies using the method:

```java
System.loadLibrary("ibex-java");
```

If I don't put these jars in the `java.library.path` the `System.loadLibrary` won't work. One remark is that I don't want to depend on the configuration of the `java.library.path` because `myapp` is mean to be a maven dependency for other projects. To solve this problem, I would like to pre-load these libraries in myapp.jar.
I tried to use the `System.load` to pre-load the files with the hope that `System.loadLibrary` would re-use this dependencies, it didn't work.

My question are:

- Is possible to pre-load a jar using `System.load` for that `System.loadLibrary` doesn't depend on checking the `java.library.path` for the dependency?
- There is a better way to pack these external files and configure them without configure the `java.library.path`?

Comment: You can't put the DLLs into the JAR file. The operating system can't use them from there. You have to put them into the file system. The difference between `load()` and `loadLibrary()` is fully specified in the Javadoc.

Comment: Yes, the copyFile method does this job. It copies all the .dll (or .so) to the SO temp folder

Comment: João, how did you solve the issue? Having the same issue right now

Comment: Hi @cilap, I couldn't find a solution to pack the DLLs with the jar. What I ended up doing was copying the DLLs to the bin folder together with the application into a docker container.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitt was it the java.library.path or a different path?

Comment: @cilap, take a look at the answer I posted for my own question. The link might give you a better idea on how I had set it up in the past.

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/schmittjoaopedro/schmittjoaopedro.github.io/blob/gh-pages/assets/other/config_ibex_choco.txt